# Exclude different subtrees from export when using different back-ends

Tags: org-export

For example, `main.org`:

```
* Heading
  * Common subheading
  * HTML subheading
  * ODT subheading
```

I want to set tags or properties in such a way, that allows to export into `main.html` HTML subheading but not ODT one:

```
* Heading
  * Common subheading
  * HTML subheading
```

And to export into `main.odt` ODT subheading but not HTML one:

```
* Heading
  * Common subheading
  * ODT subheading
```

There is an option `EXCLUDE_TAGS`, but it works on any export back-ends.  Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Insert the following stuff at the top of your orgfile.
You can then use the tags `:noexporthtml:` and `:noexportodt:` on the headings throughout the rest of the document to exclude headings from html or odt export, respectively.

```
#+OPTIONS: tags:nil
* Noexport specifications                                          :noexport:
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :exports results :eval t
(setq org-export-exclude-tags (list "noexport" (concat "noexport" (symbol-name org-export-current-backend))))
""
#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 0):

The one way I've found is to create settings file for each case:

`html.org`

```
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: odt
#+INCLUDE: main.org
```

`odt.org`

```
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: html
#+INCLUDE: main.org
```

And then export each file with its own back-end.